# Installing Basic 256 on Edubuntu

Tags: software-installation, edubuntu

I have recently installed Edubuntu in my school computer lab computers so that the students can become familiar with the Linux environment.
It's going well except I tried to install the Basic 256 application in Edubuntu, but I am facing problems with it.

The terminal commands which I used are shown below:

```
saint@saint-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo apt install basic256
[sudo] password for saint: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package basic256
saint@saint-System-Product-Name:~$
```

Comment: What did you try? Why do you think it failed?

Comment: I tried the following in terminal

Comment: Sudo apt- get update

Comment: Sudo apt- get install Basic 256

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: saint@saint-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo apt install basic256
[sudo] password for saint: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package basic256
saint@saint-System-Product-Name:~$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) and [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a package is available for Ubuntu, you can just do

```
sudo apt install basic256
```

You may have to enable [universe](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) repository in order to download this software.

Comment: How can I enable universe repository

Comment: As described on the official guide, open ***Software and updates*** app and tick Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe).

Comment: Universe repository is enabled but still I am not able to install basic256

Comment: Can you refresh the list of available package with `apt  update` and then do `apt install basic256`.